# DiscordAPIError: Unknown Interaction after making the /help command

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

So I have this help command but I am getting an error saying "Unknown Interaction". I have been searching on the internet for quite a while now, but could not find a solution for this.

Here is the code:

```
const { Client, MessageEmbed } = require("discord.js");
const { readdirSync} = require("fs");

module.exports = {
    name: "help",
    aliases: ["h"],
    userPerms: ["SEND_MESSAGES"],
    clientPerms: ["SEND_MESSAGES", "EMBED_LINKS"],
    description: "Shows all available bot commands.",
    
    execute: async(interaction, args, client, message) => {
        const {user} = interaction;
        if(!args[0]){
            let categories = [];

            readdirSync("./Commands/").forEach((dir) => {
                const commands = readdirSync(`./Commands/${dir}/`).filter((file) => file.
                endsWith(".js"))

            const cmds = commands.map((command) => {
                let file = require(`../../Commands/${dir}/${command}`)
                if(!file.name) return "No command name.";

                let name = file.name.replace(".js", "");

                return `\`${name}\``;
            });

            let data = new Object();
            data = {
                name: dir.toUpperCase(),
                value: cmds.length === 0 ? "In progress." : cmds.join(" | "),
            };
            categories.push(data);
            })

            const embed = new MessageEmbed()
            .setTitle("Commands")
            .addFields(categories)
            .setDescription(`Use /help followed by a command name to get more additional information on a command. For example: /help afk`)
            .setFooter(`Requested by ${user.tag}`, user.displayAvatarURL({dynamic: true}))
            .setColor("RANDOM");
            return interaction.reply({emebds: [embed]})
        } else {
            const command = client.commands.get(args[0].toLowerCase()) || client.commands.find((c) => c.aliases && c.aliases.includes(args[0].toLowerCase()));

            if(!command){
                const embed = new MessageEmbed()
                .setTitle("Not Found")
                .setDescription("Command not found. Use /help for all commands available")
                .setColor("RANDOM");
                return interaction.reply({embeds: [embed]})
            }
            const embed = new MessageEmbed()
            .setTitle("Command Details")
            .addField("COMMAND:", command.name ? `\`${command.name}\`` : "No name for this command")
            .addField("ALIASES:", command.aliases ? `\`${command.aliases.join("` `")}\`` : "No aliases for this command.")
            .addField("USAGE:", command.usage ? `\`/${command.name} ${command.usage}\`` : `/\`${command.name}\``)
            .addField("DESCRIPTION", command.description ? command.description : "No description for this command.")
            .setFooter(`Requested by ${message.author.tag}`, message.author.displayAvatarURL({dnyamic: true}))
            .setColor("RANDOM");

            return interaction.reply({embeds: [embed]});
        }
    }
}
```

And this is the error I am getting after typing /help on discord

```
/Users/Aplex/Documents/Aplel/node_modules/discord.js/src/rest/RequestHandler.js:350
      throw new DiscordAPIError(data, res.status, request);
            ^

DiscordAPIError: Unknown interaction
    at RequestHandler.execute (/Users/Aplex/Documents/Aplel/node_modules/discord.js/src/rest/RequestHandler.js:350:13)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
    at async RequestHandler.push (/Users/Aplex/Documents/Aplel/node_modules/discord.js/src/rest/RequestHandler.js:51:14)
    at async CommandInteraction.reply (/Users/Aplex/Documents/Aplel/node_modules/discord.js/src/structures/interfaces/InteractionResponses.js:99:5) {
  method: 'post',
  code: 10062,
  httpStatus: 404,
  requestData: {
    json: {
      type: 4,
      data: {
        content: undefined,
        tts: false,
        nonce: undefined,
        embeds: undefined,
        components: undefined,
        username: undefined,
        avatar_url: undefined,
        allowed_mentions: undefined,
        flags: undefined,
        message_reference: undefined,
        attachments: undefined,
        sticker_ids: undefined
      }
    },
    files: []
  }
}
```

Does anyone have an idea of where the issue exactly is and how to fix it? I would really appreciate it

Answer (score 0):

This normally means that you took too long to respond to the Interaction. You can add an [`interaction.deferReply()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/discord.js/stable/class/CommandInteraction?scrollTo=deferReply) to defer the reply.